# WebSocket only works when executing on local file:/// page

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I'm experimenting with HTML5 WebSockets and I got my basic client/server scenario working using [Nugget](http://nugget.codeplex.com/). However, it only works when I execute a local HTML file (`file:///`); as soon as I execute it through `http://localhost/` it fails.

So, connecting to `localhost` from a `file:///` HTML file works, but connecting to `localhost` via `http://localhost/` fails. This is weird and annoying, because I want to be able to use it in my home network.

I thought it would perhaps be because the origin is not the same (different ports), but this cannot be the cause as the ports *must* differ so as not to let Apache respond to WebSocket requests.

The client code itself is in its most basic form:

```
var ws;

function wsi() {
 ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8887/consoleappsample');

 ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
  alert(evt.data);
 }
}

window.onload = wsi;
```

Does someone see what I might be doing incorrectly?

Comment: Have you tried checking `document.domain`?

Comment: As for the file:/// file it returns an empty string (and socket works), as for the localhost it returns "localhost" (and socket does not work)

Comment: which browser are you using to test this?

Comment: Forgot to mention that; it's Chrome 9.

Comment: are you using web-socket.js? or just websocket from browser

Comment: I'm not using any extensions - just the built-in HTML5 WebSocket.

Comment: have you tried using 127.0.0.1 instead of local host?

Comment: Strangely, then it doesn't work anymore. Putting `localhost` literally is a necessity.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is similar to localhost

Comment: Indeed, but it just doesn't work then... Might be because the server listens at localhost (literally programmed in the server) and not 127.0.0.1... It is really weird.

Comment: you did a virtual host.  did you check the port to match 8887

Comment: Yes I did. The point is that it does work as expected when I access it via file:///, but that the websocket automatically gets a readyState of 2 (disconnected) when using http://localhost/. Furthermore, the server console (which shows when someone connects/diconnects) does not log anything - so the client does not connect at all when using http://localhost/.

Comment: The origin should be the same because it is the location the page was loaded from not the location where the WebSockets connection is made to.

Comment: As kanaka says, you need to load the page from http://localhost:8887/ not from http://localhost/ - localhost is not the same host as localhost:8887

Comment: But is that possible at all? If I set 8887 to be the port for the web server, Apache will respond to websocket requests, while my own server should listen to that port.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but the simplest approach is just to serve your HTML with Nugget like in [this example](http://nugget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=02%20SubProtocol&referringTitle=Documentation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve it in the end.

In the server, the following has to be added (`*` instead of `null`), replace x of course:

```
var nugget = new WebSocketServer(8887, "*", "ws://192.168.x.x:8887");
```

Then, in HandshakeHandler.cs, add this (where currently the last condition is not present):

```
if (hasRequiredFields && "ws://"+ClientHandshake.Host == Location && (ClientHandshake.Origin == Origin || Origin=="*"))
```

Thanks for all replies.